# Print a diagonal line up to the right in java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a diagonal line going up to the right. The end result should look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VKMZ.jpg . My current code has it going from the top left to the bottom right (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNqEh.jpg). I know to fix this it's a simple fix, but I'm stumped. I've looked all over google but for some reason EVERY example I come across makes it print the way I've already done.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
for(int row = grid.getHt(); row>=0; row--){
            for(int col = row; col<row+1; col++){
                if(col < grid.getWd()){
                grid.setColor(row, col, Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        } //end leg
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your `row = grid.getHt();` is starting you at the row that appears at the top of the screen instead of the bottom. Try setting `for(row = 0; r<=grid.getHt(); row++)`

Comment: I did try this prior to the code I posted. For some reason it just prints the same result. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Try switching the row col variables in your setColor method

Comment: That didn't work either. I did manage to solve it by doing one for loop for the row and making a temp variable that adds one each time the row increases. It was easier than I thought. Thanks for your help